# satellite assemblies used from a .dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, satellite-assembly

I am trying to implement satellite assemblies. My scenario though is slightly different than the ordinary case.

- I have an executable assembly ( let's call it A.exe) and a .dll
  assembly (B.dll)
- A.exe references B.dll  and A.csproj is the start up project in my
  Solution
- My Strings file is in assembly B (The class library)
- I created Satelite Assemblies and placed them in the Bin folder of
  prject B.
- The issue is that no matter which Culture I provide, it always falls
  back on the default culture which is embedded in the project.(The
  Satelite Assemblies are not)
- When I try to place the Default Strings File and the Satelite
  Assemblies in the .exe project they work, but as soon as I transfer
  them to the .dll project they don't

  Does anyone have any solution to my situation. I can't place the
  strings file in the .exe project (Business requirement)

Thanks very much in advance.

**Since I can't answer my own question in a separate reply, here is the solution:**

You need to place the Satellite Assembly's .dll files both in the library and  the executable assembly's \bin directories.

I started with the project on this site:

[Example](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/tipstricks/article.php/c11367)

and just elaborated it to include a library class. I wish there was a way to post it here...let me know if there is a way to attach projects to posts.

Comment: How about you post what you currently have so we can go from there.